# Vim copy preserving cursor location

Tags: vim, key-binding

I would like to have a shortcut in vim that performs a line duplication, without messing up the cursor's position. Simply yanking and pasting always moves the cursor to the beginning of the next line, so I think I need to do this in two steps: copying the beginning of the line and then the end of the line. What I was trying is this:

```
noremap <C-S-d> y0O<ESC>pkéy$lgp`[
```

with `hjkl` remapped to `jklé`. (without remapping it would look like this: `` y0O<ESC>pjly$kgp`[ ``.)

This does not seem to work as a command though, even though when I test it key by key, it mangaes just fine. I wonder what is wrong with this macro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem I see is that `noremap` maps the value of the left-hand side to the value of the right-hand side *without remapping*. Basically, the right-hand side is always considered as just built-in mappings.

You could use `map` instead of `noremap`, or you could use the original mappings in the left-hand side. This seems to work fine for me:

```
noremap <C-S-d> y0O<ESC>pjly$kgp`[
```

Incidentally, here's how I duplicate lines, just so you can have a different approach to think about:

```
nnoremap zj mz"yyy"yP`z
nnoremap zk mz"yyy"yP`zk
```

The steps for duplicating are:

- Save the current position in the `z` mark with `mz`
- Copy line into the `y` register with `"yyy`
- Paste line above with `"yP`
- Go to the original position with `` `z ``

For me, this keeps the cursor position in the right place.

Comment: I would recommend using another map `zj`is a fold related map.

Comment: this is clever, thank you for contributing it! there is a corner case I found almost immediately where this doesn't work as expected: when the cursor is at the start of the line. in this case, while it preserves the cursor position, it _omits_ the first character in the line. the fix is to replace `y0` with `v0y`, which covers this case.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew's answer is nearly perfect; it just doesn't work as expected when invoked at the start of a line. Here's a slightly modified keymapping which resolves this:

```
noremap <C-S-d> v0yO<ESC>pjly$kgp[`
```